# Upload Excel file which is in xml format with ASP.NET web api 2

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, excel, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to upload an excel file. The excel file is in XML format. That is when I right click and edit, its shows XML formatting. The extension of the file is .xlsx. The error that I'm getting is "External table is not in the expected format".

I'm able to upload normal excel files successfully.

My connection string is  -  Excel10ConString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;""

```
private static DataTable GetExcelFileData(ExcelReaderRequest excelFileRequest)
    {
        if (excelFileRequest == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("excelFileRequest");
        }

        string CommandText = string.Empty;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
        string strMappedPath = DocumentManagementContext.ComponentSettings.MappedPath;
        string sourcePath = string.Concat(strMappedPath, excelFileRequest.FileRelativePath);
        string connectionString = excelFileRequest.FileExtension == ".xlsx" ? DocumentManagementContext.ComponentSettings.Excel10ConString : DocumentManagementContext.ComponentSettings.Excel07ConString;
        string recordCount = excelFileRequest.MaxRecordCount == 0 ? string.Empty : string.Format("Top {0} ", excelFileRequest.MaxRecordCount + 1);
        connectionString = string.Format(connectionString, sourcePath);
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                if (excelFileRequest.FileExtension == ".xlsx" || excelFileRequest.FileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    ///// Getting the excel sheet name
                    DataTable dtSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                    string SheetName = dtSheetName.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    ///// CommandText for excel files
                    CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT {0}* FROM [{1}]", recordCount, SheetName);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ServiceException("Invalid file");
                }

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(CommandText, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    using (DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable())
                    {
                        ///// Satisfies rule: SetLocaleForDataTypes.
                        dtTemp.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                        da.Fill(dtTemp);

                        if (dtTemp != null)
                        {
                            using (DataTable dtexcelMain = CreateDataSetFromExcel(dtTemp))
                            {
                                dtexcelMain.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                                return dtexcelMain;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException("Error in GetExcelFileData message : " + Ex.Message, Ex, ExceptionType.OtherHandledException, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, true, "PT1000");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (da != null)
            {
                da.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the extension is xml it is Open Xml.  The oledb method will not read Open Xml.  See connectionstrings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/openoffice-spreadsheet/  You can also create you own xml parser use XmlReader, XmlDocument,  or XDocument.

Comment: The extension is .xlsx but the file format is XML

Comment: If the file is xml text it doesn't matter the extension.  XmlReader, XmlDocument, and XDocument will still read and parse the file.  Oledb does not read xml.

Comment: but I have to read other excel files also, how will I differentiate?

Comment: For Open xml the extension should be xml not xlsx.   Then it is easy to distinguish.

Comment: yea, but for me the extension should always be .xlsx. While downloading can be do something? According to business rules, it should be an excel file. I'm the only one who is writting code to download excel files.

Comment: What business rules?  An Open Excel file is still excel even with an XML extension.